# Why is this function not returning the correct result?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm fetching data from database by creating two functions "daySum()" and "yesterdaySum()". When calling those functions it returns correct values, 54000 and 51000 respectively.

Then I put them into variables $day and $yesterday, but when doing variable operation "$day+$yesterday" it prints 0. This won't allow me to create a conditional which is needed for my project.

Can you help me out?

Thanks in advance!

```
//DEFINING 2 FUNCTIONS: daySum() and yesterdaySum()

function daySum() {
    //connect to database
    require 'connect.php';

    // query
    $query = "SELECT sum(till_amount) FROM Cash ";
    $query .= "WHERE date ='2017-09-05'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    // fetch
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        print_r($row["sum(till_amount)"]);
    }
}

function yesterdaySum() {
    //connect to database
    require 'connect.php';

    // query
    $query = "SELECT sum(till_amount) FROM Cash ";
    $query .= "WHERE date ='2017-09-04'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    // fetch
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        print_r($row["sum(till_amount)"]);
    }
}

// PUTTING THEM INTO VARIABLE 

$day = daySum(); // sum is 54000
$yesterday = yesterdaySum(); // sum is 51000

    // adding $day plus $yesterday should print 105000
    // and here is the problem...

print($day + $yesterday); // it prints 0

//WHY????
```

Comment: Because the functions don't [return](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) anything, they just display the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function are ***just printing things***.That's why it's add is not working.

You have to change your code like below (***some improvement also*** which is commented):-

```
<?php
require 'connect.php'; //don't add multiple time
function daySum() {
    $query = "SELECT sum(till_amount) FROM Cash WHERE date ='2017-09-05'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        return $row["sum(till_amount)"]); //return value
    }
}

function yesterdaySum() {
    $query = "SELECT sum(till_amount) FROM Cash WHERE date ='2017-09-04'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       return $row["sum(till_amount)"]); //return value
    }
}

$day = daySum(); // now $day have value
$yesterday = yesterdaySum(); //now $yesterday have value


print((int)$day + (int)$yesterday); // it will work fine now
```

***Now most easy is to*** [use BETWEEN query](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/between.php):-

```
<?php
require 'connect.php'; //don't add multiple time
function daySum() {
    $query = "SELECT sum(till_amount) FROM Cash WHERE date BETWEEN '2017-09-04' AND '2017-09-05'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        return $row["sum(till_amount)"]);
    }
}

$day = daySum();

print($day);
```

***Note:-*** May be it's you homework task, but start learning about ***`prepared statements`*** today on-ward to prevent your query from ***`SQL INJECTION`***.It's important and necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried your code, but for some reason when adding variable $day and $yesterday is printing 2 (as if each function would return 1). Any suggestion?
Thanks again for your time!!

Comment: Check the result of the queries

Comment: @NicolasIbarra  use `print((int)$day + (int)$yesterday);` (i have edited in my code too.).Why don't you go for the second solution?

Comment: @AlivetoDie I erased the "print_r" part and changed it to return and it works!! Thank you very much for your help!!